# Run sqoop in python script

Tags: python, sqoop

I'm trying to run sqoop command inside Python script. I had no problem to do that trough shell command, but when I'm trying to execute python stript:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
sqoopcom="sqoop import --direct --connect abcd --username abc --P --query "queryname" "

exec (sqoopcom)
```

I got an error, Invalid syntax, how to solve it ?

Comment: Either you forgot to escape "queryname" properly or it is a parameter in which case you should concatenate with plus signs

Comment: Hi, Even if I'my trying to do: sqoopcom="sqoop"
exec sqoopcom
I got an error : NameError: name 'sqoop' is not defined

Comment: Oh sorry. exec is actually for executing python code. Your probably looking for an appropriate call inside the subprocess module or something similar for executing shell commands.

Comment: Yep, you are right, any advise  ?

Comment: Ok I found. I used import os. But the other question is if there is a possibility to run sqoop function without that ? using some python library ?

Comment: As I mentioned. In the module `subprocess` there is `call` for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118806/discussion-between-synthomat-and-maciek2791).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build in `exec` statement that you're using is for interpreting python code inside a python program.

What you want is to execute an external (shell) command. For that you could use `call` from the **subprocess module**

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["echo", "Hello", "World"])
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Okay Thanks. Is it possible to assign some variable into that command ? (variable as input to script)

Comment: Just use as many arguments inside the call command as you need

Answer (score 2):

You need to skip " on --query param

```
sqoopcom="sqoop import --direct --connect abcd --username abc --P --query \"queryname\" --target-dir /pwd/dir --m 1 --fetch-size 1000 --verbose --fields-terminated-by , --escaped-by \\ --enclosed-by '\"'/dir/part-m-00000"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:
Invalid syntax error noted that you haven't backslashed \"queryname\"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
sqoopcom="sqoop import --direct --connect abcd --username abc --P --query \"queryname\" "
os.system(sqoopcom)
```